# Is it possible to boot without adding `pci=nomsi` or `acpi=off` to the grub command line?

Tags: grub2, kernel, asus

I have an ASUS X64SL laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 CPU.

When I want to boot with Linux I have to add to the grub command line either `pci=nomsi` or `acpi=off`.

Is there another way to boot without adding any of these two lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Follow these steps precisely**

- Start your system as your traditional way :) Then open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute these commands:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```

  once `grub` is opened in `gedit` replace

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  ```

  by

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
  ```

  Save and close `gedit` window.
- Update grub and restart your system:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  sudo reboot
  ```

Your system should starts normally. Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: It's working but my question is is there a possible way to boot without writing pci=nomsi in any part of the grub (not directly in grub.cfg nor in any other place)

Comment: Actually I gave the answer according to your previous question, i,e before edit of your question. Since you had to manually set every time the grub option, my answer solves this issue and starts normally without any further interaction. I appreciate your enthusiasm to know more about this. I recommend you to read more about [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) and [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1327209). I think for your case you've to use that option. Hope these links are useful.

Comment: does pci=nomsi work for all laptop beacause im using a omen 15 and it shows me online to use pci=nommconf instead of pci=nomsi

Comment: I did this and now my computer crashes on the login, it does not allow me to move the mouse or enter my password.

Comment: @EnmanuelDurán: Oh I'm sorry to know this. If you've followed the steps and took a backup of the file *grub* then you can revert it back to original by renaming *grub.bak* to *grub*.