# Ubuntu: Monitors randomly turn off

Tags: 16.04, display

I have been trying to solve this for two days without any luck.

I installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 16.04, overwriting a previous install of the same version. Ever since the reinstall, every once in a while both of my monitors will turn blank with the "no input" text. Nothing I do can wake them up. Mouse and keyboard also become unresponsive, but the computer is still running and if I'm playing music, it will continue uninhibited.

The only way to get it working is to do a hard shutdown and then turn it back on.

This problem can occur after 10 minutes or a couple of hours. It happens when doing various activities, so no idea what is triggering it. I could be playing a game, browing the web, or literally doing nothing when it occurs.

I have tried the `xset` fix with no luck.

```
xset s off
xset s noblank
xset -dpms
```

Brightness & Lock is set to Never and Power is set to Don't Suspend.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your problem. I had the same issue, as you described, with my system and I finally solved the issue.

Check your syslog under /var/log. If you find PCIe bus errors (you will probably see alot) add the "pci=nomsi" flag to the Linux kernel command line. Go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353502/is-it-possible-to-boot-without-adding-pci-nomsi-or-acpi-off-to-the-grub-comm) for instructions on how to do this.